# sld responsive inline view of cards

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have following code that display advisors information with image or with name initials.
this code is working fine with desktop mobile tablet, But I am having problem to allign these
cards inline for landescape mode in case of 768 width.

```
<div data-id="advisorSection" Class="tg-gap-24">
<template for:each={advisorsInPage} for:item="advisoryTeamMember">
                        <lightning-layout class="td-inner-frame1" key={advisoryTeamMember.id}>
                            <lightning-layout-item>
                                <img if:true={advisoryTeamMember.isPhotoPresent} src={advisoryTeamMember.FullPhotoUrl}
                                    alt="User Image" class="td-ellipse-26" />
                                <span if:false={advisoryTeamMember.isPhotoPresent}
                                    class="td-icon-button-utility td-icon-button-utility-circle td-icon-button-utility-white-bg hover td-circle">
                                    <span class="td-body-15-plain"
                                        style="color:#FFFFFF;">{advisoryTeamMember.initials}</span>
                                </span>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item class="td-inner-frame2">
                                <div class="td-body-15 td-parent-truncate">
                                    <span class="td-truncate"
                                        title={advisoryTeamMember.Name}>{advisoryTeamMember.Name}</span>
                                </div>
                                <template if:true={advisoryTeamMember.Persona__c}>
                                    <div class="td-body-15 td-parent-truncate">
                                        <span class="td-truncate"
                                            title={advisoryTeamMember.Persona__c}>{advisoryTeamMember.Persona__c}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="td-body-15-plain">
                                        <lightning-formatted-phone value={advisoryTeamMember.Phone}>
                                        </lightning-formatted-phone>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="td-parent-truncate">
                                    <lightning-formatted-email class="td-body-15-plain td-truncate" style="color:#008A00;"
                                        title={advisoryTeamMember.Email} value={advisoryTeamMember.Email}
                                        hide-icon></lightning-formatted-email>
                                </div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
</template>
</div>
```

and I have create following CSS after googling.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .td-inner-frame1 {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
    width: 720px;  
    height: 260px; 
  }

  .td-inner-frame1 > lightning-layout-item {
    flex: 1; 
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .td-inner-frame1 > lightning-layout-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px; 
  }
}
```

I try following Css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .td-inner-frame1 {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
    width: 720px;  
    height: 260px; 
  }

  .td-inner-frame1 > lightning-layout-item {
    flex: 1; 
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .td-inner-frame1 > lightning-layout-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your CSS query to align the cards inline for landscape mode at 768px width. Hope the following helps

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .tg-gap-24 {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .td-inner-frame1 {
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px); 
        margin: 10px; 
        height: auto; 
    }
}
```